# Broken jQuery 1.4.2 functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code worked prior to the upgrade from 1.3.2. to 1.4.2 and now I'm getting this error I don't know what to do with...:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: '/ajax/store/product/getAssocDetail.ph',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    //productId: (document.location+"").split("=")[1],
    vehicleId: id
  },
  success: function () {/*
    if (r.length > 0) {
      console.log(r.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        jQuery('#condition-'+i+'-price').val(r[i].price);
        jQuery('#condition-'+i+'-bid').val(r[i].bid);/*
        if (parseInt(r[i].on_amazon) == 1) {
          jQuery('#on_amazon-'+i+'-yes').attr('checked', 'checked');
        } else {
          jQuery('#on_amazon-'+i+'-no').attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
        console.log('[value='+r[i].on_amazon+']');
        console.log(jQuery('#condition-'+r[i].condition_id+'-on_amazon').filter('[value='+r[i].on_amazon+']'));
        jQuery('#condition-'+r[i].condition_id+'-on_amazon').filter('[value='+r[i].on_amazon+']').attr('checked', true);
      }

      jQuery('#assocation-detail').show();
    } else {
      triggerNotification('x', 'Could not find any assocation data');
    }*/
  },
  error: function () {
    //document.triggerNotification('x', 'Unable to process your request, ajax file not found');
    return false;
  }
});
```

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"  nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)"  location: "JS frame :: http://internal.ikeyless/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js :: f :: line 132"  data: no]
>
> Line 0

**update**

The error appears to be here on line 5437 of uncompressed jQuery 1.4.2 (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js)

```
    function add( key, value ) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = jQuery.isFunction(value) ? value() : value;
        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
```

**update**

The issue was that one of the values being posted via ajax was a dom node :-\

Comment: The jQuery-code looks fine. What is `document.triggerNotification` for? Do you use this as a global function? Global functions should not be appended to `document`. Try `window` instead.

Comment: Did you ever get the `triggerNotification` to fire the way you wanted? (referring to your previous question)

Comment: Instead of the compressed version of jQuery try the developer version, and if the error happens there then you will be able to get a line number !, and items in your code is not normal, such as `document.body` within the jQuery param and the setTimeout not being wrapped n an anonymous function...

Comment: Since the lack of a function passed to `setTimeout` was not the issue, everything else looks correct, so I'd have to assume that the cause of the error has been edited out of your question. Could you post more code?

Comment: Works ok here :/ http://jsfiddle.net/gnw4x/1/

Comment: @RobertPitt - that still gives the "missing ] after element list" error. I know that's not the OP's problem but it's an error nonetheless.

Comment: How did you get line `5437` when the error states `132` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue was that one of the values being posted via ajax was a dom node :-\

Why this happens:

jQuery is trying to serialise the node as a generic `{}`-style object lookup. Using a `for..in` loop it fetches each property of the node including DOM methods like `appendChild`. The `add` function quoted checks to see whether the value is a function, and if so, calls it. A method is a function, so it calls `node.appendChild` as a plain function, without `this` set to point to an actual `Node` instance. This causes the characteristic XPC error.

jQuery 1.3 did not have the (rather pointless IMO) feature of being able to pass a callable function into a parameter mapping, so you don't get this error. It's still not sensible to serialise a DOM Node, but it fails silently instead of blowing up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `fadeOut` code in an anonymous function...

```
document.triggerNotification = function (type, message) {
    jQuery(document.body).append("<div class='push-notification push-"+type+"' id='notification'>"+message+"</div>");

    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#notification').fadeOut(1200, function () {
            jQuery('#notification').remove();
        })
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: You're correct, but it was covered. I deleted because it didn't cause the issue OP is having. I should have placed a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(document.body)` seems a bit suspicious to me, though cannot be too sure.

Try `jQuery("body")` instead.

[This link](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_thread/thread/48e2acab9b0a0db2/e60ce4e26c58e772?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=%22Illegal+operation+on+WrappedNative+prototype+object%22&pli=1) is kind-of loosely-related and was caused my aliasing `document.createElement`. Sounds like this may be the same thing.

Can you verify on which line it is actually failing?

Comment: Using `document.body` shouldn't make a difference in jQuery 1.4. You can still pass a DOM element directly.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but sometimes "shouldn't" and "doesn't" aren't the same thing.

Comment: `document.body` is fine, it's exactly what `"body"` gets translated into, so `document.body` directly is more efficient as well.

Comment: @Nick - Thanks. Learned something today!